# sql server data type and return value from select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I designed a table with one field of type char(10).
I then I input data to this field but data is less than 10 characters.
Why is it that when I select the data, it returns the data appended with spaces to 10 characters?

Comment: that's the way char(n) is designed to work.

Comment: @MitchWheat: exactly - WAD - works as designed !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*char(n) **is** padding data with spaces  ( completed to n)*